# Trading strategies for illiquid markets

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies

Is there any literature on trading strategies for illiquid equities markets, such as research papers or articles?  I've done some searching but haven't turned anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a research paper on that:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f879/c1268cfadcd721dfabc643cf28434b88f556.pdf